# calling mechanize inside scala failed:HtmlDocument cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothin

Tags: scala

I have the following code to use mechanize (could be download from https://github.com/GistLabs/mechanize)

```
import com.gistlabs.mechanize._
val agent = new MechanizeAgent();
val page = agent.get("http://www.ask.com");
```

It failed saying the following, how could I make it works?

```
scala> agent.get("http://www.ask.com")
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gistlabs.mechanize.document.html.HtmlDocument cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `MechanizeAgent.get` is a generic method (see [line 182 in MechanizeAgent.java](https://github.com/GistLabs/mechanize/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gistlabs/mechanize/MechanizeAgent.java#L182)). So you must tell Scala what type to expect. Either like this:

```
import com.gistlabs.mechanize._
import com.gistlabs.mechanize.document._

val agent = new MechanizeAgent();
val page = agent.get[Document]("http://www.ask.com");
```

or like this:

```
import com.gistlabs.mechanize._
import com.gistlabs.mechanize.document._

val agent = new MechanizeAgent();
val page: Document = agent.get("http://www.ask.com");
```